# Spring Boot Caching with Redis Sentinel always connects to master node

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel

I have a Spring Boot (2.3.1.RELEASE) app that has caching with Redis Sentinel.
This is my configuration for the Sentinel connection:

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
   RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration()
            .master(redisProperties.getSentinel().getMaster());
    redisProperties.getSentinel().getNodes().forEach(s -> sentinelConfig.sentinel(s, redisProperties.getPort()));
    sentinelConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisProperties.getPassword()));
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
}
```

And this is my caching manager configuration:

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager() {
    Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> cacheConfigs = new HashMap<>();
    cacheConfigs.put("cache1", RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(ttlMinutes)));
    cacheConfigs.put("cache2", RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(ttlMinutes)));

    return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory())
            .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(ttlMinutes)))
            .withInitialCacheConfigurations(cacheConfigs)
            .transactionAware()
            .build();
}
```

Everything works fine from caching perspective.

However, If I turn on debug logs inside the `io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler`, I see that it is always connecting to the same node (master). Which I can confirm by looking at the logs on the node.

Everywhere I look online, this seems like the correct configuration.

This brings me to my question:

- **Is it possible to configure the Spring caching abstraction to use the master node only for writes and the slave nodes for reads?**

Is this expectation even valid? Or this is the way Sentinel is supposed to be used (all requests go to master)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, it can be done.**

From **[Spring Data Redis Docs - 10.4.4. Write to Master, Read from Replica](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) :**

> It is said that **Spring Data Redis** provides a **Redis Master/Replica setup** which not
> only allows data to be safely stored at more nodes but also allows
> reading data from replicas while pushing writes to the master by using
> **Lettuce**.

For this, you have to update `redisConnectionFactory()` method in the configuration class :

```
 @Bean
 public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
   LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED)
            .build();
   RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration()
            .master(redisProperties.getSentinel().getMaster());
   redisProperties.getSentinel().getNodes().forEach(s -> sentinelConfig.sentinel(s, redisProperties.getPort()));
   sentinelConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisProperties.getPassword()));
   return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig, clientConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write master and read only from **all** slaves(replicas), you can use below configuration.

These configurations include connection pooling,write to master and **read from all slave nodes with round-robin load balancing.**

```
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties, LettucePoolingClientConfiguration lettucePoolingClientConfiguration) {
        final RedisSentinelConfiguration redisSentinelConfiguration = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master(redisProperties.getMaster());
        redisSentinelConfiguration.setDatabase(redisProperties.getDbIndex());
        addSentinels(redisProperties, redisSentinelConfiguration);
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisSentinelConfiguration, lettucePoolingClientConfiguration);
    }

    private void addSentinels(RedisProperties redisProperties, RedisSentinelConfiguration redisSentinelConfiguration) {
        redisProperties.getNodes()
                .forEach(node -> {
                    final String[] splitted = node.split(NODE_SPLITTER);
                    final String host = splitted[0];
                    final int port = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
                    redisSentinelConfiguration.addSentinel(RedisNode.newRedisNode()
                            .listeningAt(host, port)
                            .build());
                });
    }

    @Bean
    public LettucePoolingClientConfiguration lettucePoolingClientConfiguration(ClientOptions clientOptions, ClientResources clientResources, RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        return LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
                .readFrom(ReadFrom.ANY_REPLICA)
                .poolConfig(genericObjectPoolConfig(redisProperties))
                .clientOptions(clientOptions)
                .clientResources(clientResources)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        final GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        config.setMaxIdle(redisProperties.getPoolMaxIdle());
        config.setMinIdle(redisProperties.getPoolMinIdle());
        config.setMaxTotal(redisProperties.getPoolMaxTotal());
        config.setBlockWhenExhausted(false);
        config.setMaxWaitMillis(redisProperties.getPoolMaxWaitMillis());
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientOptions clientOptions(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
        return ClientOptions.builder()
                .autoReconnect(true)
                .disconnectedBehavior(ClientOptions.DisconnectedBehavior.REJECT_COMMANDS)
                .timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.builder().fixedTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(redisProperties.getCommandTimedOutSec())).build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ClientResources clientResources() {
        return DefaultClientResources.create();
    }
```

you should import new lettuce core version for load balance read mode(**ReadFrom.ANY_REPLICA**), it will come with spring-boot 2.4.0

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```